# Are there any handheld slide viewers that work with a carousel?

Tags: slides

I don't know if this exists—but—am looking for a slide viewer that you can hook a carousel into yet view in a box as opposed to projecting it.
Dad has a zillion slides but at 94 can't handle a projector, etc.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's lots of box options but I don't know of any that work off of a carousel

Comment: Kodak used to make a couple of Ektagraphic models that do exactly what you want, and I'd be very surprised if you couldn't find one on eBay or somewhere else for not much money.

Comment: @Blrfl, why not post that as an answer? See: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge

Comment: @inkista:  Seems too short on content.

Comment: @Blrfl Nothing wrong with a short answer, if it actually answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think I've ever seen anything handheld that would work with a carousel; the whole affair would be kind of unwieldy.

Kodak used to make a couple of Ektagraphic models, the [270 and 570](http://slideprojector.kodak.com/audioViewer/kodak_ektagraphic_audioviewer_270_570.shtml), that do exactly what you're after.  Both are cube-shaped (about a foot in each dimension) and are completely self-contained.

I'd be very surprised if you couldn't find one on eBay or somewhere else for not much money.

Comment: yep, e.g.   http://www.ebay.com/itm/Kodak-Ektagraphic-270-Carousel-Type-Slide-Projector-Autoviewer-in-Case-Manual-/322272633623?hash=item4b08f22317:g:IPYAAOSwqBJXWw9o

Answer (score 1):

I recommend sending the slides in to a slide digitizing service. That way, your father could view them on whatever device is available — computer, tablet computer, smartphone, etc. Unless a "zillion" slides are so many as to be cost prohibitive to have digitized, that is.

Alternately, there are several slide viewers that will project slides onto a built-in screen (usually about 2" × 2" or so). Unfortunately, these viewers do not accept carousels. You have to load the slides individually, or some of them allow you to load a small stack (10-ish) of slides. Some of these slide viewers are powered with batteries and have an internal lamp. The cheapest slide viewers you simply hold up to your eye — they look like an enlarged jeweler's loupe, or a single-eye ViewMaster.

Examples:

- [Pana-Vue 1 Lighted 2x2 Slide Film Viewer for 35mm](https://amzn.com/B00009UTWC)
- [Pana-Vue 2 Illuminated Slide Viewer](https://amzn.com/B0000AE6G9)
- [Pana-vue 3 Slide Viewer for Viewing 35mm Transparencies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002GRLL8)

Comment: There really are a zillion.  I have a slide viewer but it is tedious to load and reload. I also have the single eye ones.  Thanks for your help - this is an interesting site.